# Java script : onclick event in check box not working in IE 8 when using css class for checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with IE 8. since my code is successfully runs on ither major browsers like mozila, chrome, and even IE 9 . but I cant able to trigger the onclick event for check box in IE 8.  my code sample is ,

```
function checkboxcheck(index){
    alert('select');

}
```

here I have used the different image by replacing the check box. and my Html code is,

```
<input type='checkbox' class='rating'  id="sample"    onclick='checkboxcheck(parameters)'  />
                    <label for="sample"></label>
```

CSS:

```
.rating {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url('../images/white_small.png') ;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:hover {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url('../images/golden_small.png') ;

}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url('../images/golden_small.png') ;
}
```

my problem is checkboxcheck(index) function is not triggerd when I click the check box which is in the form of other image.

**If I remove `class` attribute , onclick function is triggered**
***I dont know why onclick is not called when putting class attribute for checkbox***

kindly guide me. Thanks in advence.....

Comment: Instead of posting fake code, actually include what you're using. For example, what is `parameters` that you're using in the inline event handler? And what is `if (some condition)`? What isn't working? Are you getting the `alert` at all? Have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: The ID in your sample HTML is 'sample', yet in your code it's row*i...can you post the 'proper' HTML?

Also are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: @lan , even I couldnt get alert that I made in the very beginning of function call

Comment: Just a tip for a better maintainable code: You should keep the JavaScript out of the HTML to make the code more maintainable. Instead of using the "onclick" attribute in the HTML you should in your JavaScript code use: `document.getElementById("sample").addEventListener("click", function () {
                checkboxcheck(parameters);
            });`

If you are lucky, this maybe also solves your problem! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Instead of calling the method in the html, you can assign it in the javascript file.
for example using jQuery:

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox'  id="sample"   class="myclass"  />
<label for="sample"></label>
```

jQuery

```
$('.myclass').click(checkboxcheck(parameters));
```

I don't know if this code solve your problem, but maybe yes

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my application. I just changed the doctype and it worked...
Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```